# HttpOnly cookie is undefined when reaches the backend middleware

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cookies, jwt

I am working on my auth implementation for a side project of mine and I am stuck trying to authorize the user sensing the httpOnly cookie with the token to each subsequent request after login.
The workflow is the following:

- login req from the FE
- login res from the BE that sets the cookie httpOnly
- POST req from FE where I pass credentials: true
- in the BE I allow for the credentials in cors
- in the BE I have a middleware that takes the access_token from the cookie and does all its logic
  BUT the token in the middleware does not arrive, and I think it is because it has not been set in the cookie storage of the browser after the login.
  I may be wrong anyway.

This is the response from the BE to the login request:

```
 return res
  .cookie("access_token", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    // secure: true, // Ensure cookie is sent over HTTPS
    secure: false, // Set to false for HTTP (localhost). Use true for HTTPS (production).
    path: '/', // Ensures the cookie is available for all paths
    sameSite: 'lax', // Helps with CSRF protection; strict is better than lax for security reasons
    maxAge: 3600000, // Optional: sets cookie expiry time in milliseconds (1 hour here)
    // secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', // Only use Secure in production
    // sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'strict' : 'lax', // Adjust SameSite for local development
  })
  .status(200)
  .json({
    authenticated: true,
    token,
    result: [{
      id: user._id,
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email,
      verified: user.verified
    }]
  });
```

while this is just a test to get info from the BE about an user which should send the token in the cookies access_token.
This is the login function

```
      fetch(`${api}/user/get-username`, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: 'include',  // This ensures cookies are included with the request
        redirect: 'follow',
        referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
        body: JSON.stringify(email)

      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => console.log('data', data))
```

In the server I have cors that allow cookies and the domain localhost:3000

```
const corsOptions = {
 origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN, // localhost:3000
 credentials: true, // Allow cookies
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
```

And I implemented a middleware that should take the cookie access_token but it is always undefined:

```
const checkAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
console.log('req: ', req.cookies);
const token = req.cookies['access_token'];
console.log('tokens: ',  token);
```

As per my understanding I should have the cookie set in the cookie storage after the login, but this is not happening as I only see the access_token in the response header as Set-Cookie: access_token(and the token here).
Is the problem that the cookie is not stored in the cookie storage? If yes why this is not happening?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved by deleting all the properties after httpOnly from the response.
I also suggest you to ditch the httpOnly and go save the token in the localstorage directly. It is safe, contrary to what many other say

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).